# Share software installed on Windows server

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2012

I just ask if I can install software such as (Adobe Photoshop) then share it between local clients to use in same time.

Thanks advance

Comment: You tagged this with Network Shares are you intending to put the installation files on the network and then share it or are you going with install on the server and then RDP in for example to use it?

Comment: The best answer to your question regarding adobe's products you can find [here](http://www.adobe.com/legal/licenses-terms.html#desktop)

Comment: @Alex I asked if it's possible technically that sharing the software generally.
Is sharing back to licenses?

Comment: @CharlesLudlow I meaning install and sharing the file/application on the local network to use a multi and saving a hardware. Not RDP

Comment: Technically - yes, it possible if software support it, but in case of Photoshop one can use adobe's creative cloud for multi user access but there no networked licenses for w2k12

Answer (score 1):

This will not work.

The problem is that the Adobe products require certain files / registry entries that need to be there for the program to start. Not to mention that Adobe CS apps can become very disk intensive. Also you would need to consider licensing which as far as I know they do not make a network based licence you would be looking at a team purchase of Adobe CS / CC. http://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/business/teams.html